# Android 11 - Does google location accuracy/Wifi scanning work better with more buildings around you/more Wifi signals?

Tags: android-11, location-services

Would more Wi-fi signals mean location is more accurately displayed or is it the opposite? I live in an apartment on the 2nd floor and there are some big buildings around me. Will this improve accuracy?

Comment: You need to be logged into a wifi network for it to triangulate your location //are you logged into all those wifi networks?

Comment: No, but I recently found out that wi-fi scanning DOES work when wi-fi is off, which indicates it uses other wi-fi signals around you to indicate location. Though I'm not sure if it also uses your connected wi-fi. However, google location accuracy does use your connected wi-fi signal to find your location, and probably doesn't use other wi-fi signals around you.

Comment: @beeshyams The link is about Wifi scanning limitations to apps. I don't think they apply to the Google system location provider which does perform the Wifi location triangulation. You are also wrong regarding the requirements, the triangulation is based on the Wifi AP MAC address which is then checked in the worldwide Google Wifi AP database.